# How to stop message "Unfortunately, Google Play Services has stopped"[android5.1 nexus5]

Tags: android

I recently upgraded my nexus5 to android5.1,this message is often displayed.
I tried clearing the cache of the app, installing updates of the app, etc.
Is there a definitive way to stop this from showing up?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: This question better suits on this site [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did. 
1. Disable Android Device Manager (it prevents you from messing with Google Play Services 
2. Go To Application Manager, find Google Play Services 
3. Force Stop It, Clear Cache and Uninstall Updates 
Believe Me, It Worked

Comment: This deserves much more credit, it was the only solution which worked among those I tried

Answer (score 0):

I googled the question and got following answer:

1. what solved this for me (on my Nexus 5) was getting the App Info from the "Google Play" app, select force stop and then uninstall update. After a device reboot these notifications were gone (at least for now)
2. I had the same issue on my Asus Zenfone. I went into the app settings, forced closure of all Google and Google play services and cleared the data and cache for them. When I was done I rebooted the phone and so far everything is running well.

I got this from [answer link](http://forums.androidcentral.com/ask-question/445111-how-fix-unfortunately-google-play-services-has-stopped-problem-my-nexus-7-2012-a.html)

To uninstall the updates, go to apps->Google Play Store>Google play services-> Uninstall updates

Comment: @adsion I only knew these steps. If you found any do post answer.